# Foreign key on primary key on delete SQL

Tags: sql, on-delete

Premise: I'm new to the databases world and trying to slowly understand it.

I have this database of a generic company, with two tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MEMBER 
(
    Card numeric PRIMARY KEY, 
    Name character varying (16) NOT NULL, 
    Surname character varying (20) NOT NULL
); 

CREATE TABLE PAYROLL 
(
    Amount numeric NOT NULL CHECK (Amount > 0), 
    Year numeric NOT NULL, 
    Month numeric NOT NULL, 
    Employee numeric REFERENCES MEMBER(Card), 
    PRIMARY KEY (Employee, Year, Month)
);
```

Suppose the company fires a bunch of employees along the year, but wants to keep track of the money spent to pay the fired members of the staff during their months of work, in order to calculate the total spending of the year. I don't know how to keep track of their payrolls and differentiate them from other fired employees' payrolls.

Is there a way to accomplish my request without introducing attributes to the tables?

The only `ON DELETE` options I can set when creating the foreign reference of `Employee` on `PAYROLL` are `CASCADE` and `NO ACTION`, since the attribute is part of a primary key and can't be set neither null nor default (on delete set null/default).

Comment: "*Is there a way to accomplish my request without introducing attributes to the tables?*" Are you saying you *can't* add columns, or you don't want to? You'll probably want `employed_at` and `employed_until` fields.

Comment: What database and version are you using, please?

Comment: The general rule is to never delete any staff or payment data. (I.e. use foreign key RESTRICT option. And don't grant unnecessary UPDATE/DELETE privileges.)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to accomplish my request without introducing attributes to the tables?

You'd have to change the primary key to a unique constraint. These treat nulls as distinct values. Then add a simple integer primary key so you can refer to individual rows.

You can set `payroll.employee` to null. Most databases support `on delete set null`. If not, you can write a [delete trigger](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-triggers/).

However, you lose information about your payroll. Let's say a mistake is found at the end of the year. Which employee didn't get paid or got paid too much? Dunno.

And since employee would be nullable, one can accidentally add a payroll item with no employee harming [referential integrity](https://database.guide/what-is-referential-integrity/). This is an issue with deleting records for purposes other than deleting records (ie. employee is no longer employed here).

---

What you can do is add more information to employee. `employed_at` (not null) and `employed_until` (nullable) timestamp or date columns, with a compound index probably of `(employed_until, employed_at)`. Then you can use that information to filter out who is still employed. You can also add employees before they're employed, and add employment end dates before they leave.

A [view](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_ref_create_view.asp) will help avoid mistakes.

```
create view current_employees as
select *
from employees
-- employed_until may be null, null doesn't compare
-- pick something arbitrarily far into the future
where employed_at < now() and now() < coalesce(employed_until, '9999-01-01')
```

Most of your queries should use that view.

For performance and ease of dropping old employee records, you can partition your table on `employed_until is null`.

---

A few notes about your schema...

- [`numeric`](https://www.sqltutorial.net/numeric.html) is for exact precision decimal numbers. For example, you might use `numeric(8,2)` (8 digits, 2 are decimal) for the price of something like 654321.12, your `amount` column. If you just want a number, use [`integer`](https://www.sqltutorial.net/integer.html) or because 2 billion comes faster than you'd think [`bigint`](https://www.sqltutorial.net/bigint.html).
- Do not arbitrarily restrict `character varying` (`varchar`) columns. You're not saving any space, the database will use only as much space will be used as needed for each value. You don't want to tell Mr. Wolfeschlegel­stein­hausen­berger­dorff they can't have a job because their name won't fit in the database. Just use `varchar(255)`.
- Declare your [foreign keys](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_ref_foreign_key.asp). `payroll.employee` should be a foreign key of `member`. That's the only way `on delete` will work. More importantly, it enforces referential integrity.
- Declare everything `not null` unless you have a good reason it should allow nulls, otherwise nulls will sneak in where they should not be. It's easier to remove a `not null` constraint if necessary than to try to add it later and figure out what all those null values were supposed to be.
- Avoid storing dates in multiple columns. It makes indexing and date math harder. Instead, use a `date` at the beginning of the month. You can enforce this with a `check` constraint.

Comment: Note that numeric(8,2) is needed for 654321.12. (8 is the total number of digits, 2 for the decimals.) And I use nvarchar for persons, in case Müller, Bjørnson, Papadopoulos or ジャールー shows up.

Comment: @jarlh That always trips me up about numeric. nvarchar is specific to SQL Server.

Comment: nchar/nvarchar is the ANSI/ISO SQL data type for Unicode data. (However, some dbms's can store Unicode in varchar.)

Comment: @jarlh So it is! However, I wouldn't advise nvarchar in generic SQL advice, character set support is messy.

Comment: If you store Unicode data you don't have to deal with different character sets as ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1), ISO-8859-7 (Latin Greek) etc. At least in theory. Data input/output can still be a mess.

Comment: @jarlh Until you try to use any character based functions. And, of course, which Unicode character encoding? UTF-8? UTF-16LE? UTF-16BE? etc. Character encoding is a pain, but ignoring them is worse.